# How to convert database tables to doctrine entities

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line, doctrine

I am using doctrine and codeigniter and I have an existing db.[this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#convert-mapping-information) tool supposedly enables generating models from a database.

I try :

```
php doctrine.php orm:convert-mapping --from-database
```

But I get a Runtime exception (NOt enough arguments)

any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Try like this,

**For the XML output**

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database --namespace='Entities\' xml mapping/xml
```

**For the YAML output**

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database --namespace='Entities\' yml mapping/yml
```

After that you should create entities like this,

```
php doctrine orm:generate-entities
```

Help,

```
php doctrine orm:generate-entities --help
```

For the more information, [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html)

Comment: This works, but this exports XML, I would like real models in PHP with attribute definition and get set methods. Is that possible?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what to do here I try: php doctrine.php orm:generate-entities --generate-methods xml mapping/xml.  But I get no metadata classes to processs

Answer (score 5):

You missed some arguments like project full path

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace='Entities\' --force --from-database  annotation your/project/full/path
```